# Azure eventhub as kafka : Topic Authorization issue

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I created a event hub namespace with kafka enabled and create a eventhub with access policy of 'Manage, send and listen'. I am able to produce to this message but get error "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: ".

Parameters in my Akka consumer is:

```
akka.kafka.consumer {
  #Akka Kafka consumer properties defined here
  wakeup-timeout=60s

  # Properties defined by org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
  # defined in this configuration section.
  kafka-clients {
    request.timeout.ms=60000
    group.id=$Default

    bootstrap.servers=“<EventbusDomain>:9093"
    sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
    security.protocol=SASL_SSL
    sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\”<Connection String\”;”
  }
}
```

Could you please assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by fixing the kafka version in pom.xml. Apparently, Azure supports versions above kafka 0.10 only . Once I changed the dependencies then It was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this issue from yesterday onwards and added below property to fix the issue.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=false
```

Please note that we are using spring cloud + azure event hub

However, I am unable to receive messages from event hub.